# grep search recursive not working

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to find a string across all log files and list those filenames.

And these log files are in sub-directories and these files are compressed with gz so using zgrep.

I am using below command

```
zgrep -lFR --include=Std_20170101*  "ReceiveData: Receive call failed" /logs/nas/App02/201612* >> zfileslist
```

I am using --include=Std_20170101* are the files names in all subdirectories after App02 location . so to save time using above context.

I am sure that we have entries in those dates log files but some how its not showing them.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--include-dir` option since `--include` is restricted to only files:

```
zgrep -lFR --include-dir="Std_20170101*" "ReceiveData: Receive call failed" /logs/nas/App02/201612* >> zfileslist
```

From `grep` man page:

> ```
> **--include**
>   If specified, only files matching the given filename pattern are searched.
>   Note that --exclude patterns take priority over --include patterns.  
>   Patterns are matched to the full path specified, not only to the filename component.
>
> **--include-dir**
>   If -R is specified, only directories matching the given filename pattern are searched.
>   Note that --exclude-dir patterns take priority over --include-dir patterns.
> ```

Comment: Did you try putting the pattern in double quotes?

Comment: I think you have a typo in your command - you are looking for 2017 log files in 2016 log directories.  I think that is the reason for not getting any results.

Comment: files are there that's why , actually we drop new files in the old date folder and when it reached certain size we create a new folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give pattern then use find with -exec option and run grep on the files returned.

`find ./ -name "*.dat" -exec grep "find pattern" {} \;`